# How does one keep an array representative of its class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I take a number `Object` like so :

```
@objects = Object.all[1..5]
```

I no longer can perform a `where` method on `@object`.

Is there anyway, I can still perform..

```
@objects.where(:attribute => identity)
```

So long as I know all the objects are of the same class?

Comment: I'm afraid you are not, for where you need ActiveRecord collection, not an array. Try to use `limit(5)` instead of `[1..5]` or something like this.

Comment: It was just for example purposes of making an array of mutual objects in the same class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you triggered `all` an Array instance is returned, so answer to your question is **no**. There are some gotchas, though:

1. Keep a scope variable. I.e. if you need to use a scoped object in multiple places, do the following:

   ```
   objects = Object.scoped

   all_objects     = objects.all
   special_objects = objects.where(attribute: something_special).all
   ```
2. Continue playing with scoping:

   ```
   objects = Object.skip(1).take(5)

   all_objects     = objects.all
   special_objects = objects.where(attribute: something_special).all
   ```
3. Hacky and inefficient way:

   ```
   all_objects     = Object.all[1..5]
   special_objects = object.select { |object| object.attribute == something_special }
   ```

Comment: ++ on calling `select` hackey. :D